# SQL Server stored procedure does not raise an exception

Tags: sql-server, python-3.6, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure in `SQL Server 2017` that inserts a row in a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertsomething]
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
... #insert statement here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'Failed'
    THROW;
END CATCH
END
```

When calling the `insertsomething` procedure using `pyodbc.execute`, I only get the 'Failed' result using `fetchone()` function in the `cursor`.

```
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('{CALL dbo.insertsomething (?, ? ...)}', params)
    result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
except Exception as e:
    raise
```

Calling `nextset` does not raise an error. It seems that `THROW` does not return an error because of the first *result set*. Is there any properties or method that I can call or use to raise the error coming from `THROW`? I don't have permission to modify our `stored procedure` so I must catch the exception in application level.

Comment: Remove `SELECT 'Failed'` and use `THROW 'Failed'`. You used `fetchone` which returns the first result. With the current code, that's `'Failed'`. `fetchone()` doesn't check whether the stored procedure throws later on

Comment: I stated in my post that modifying the stored procedure is not possible in my case. Is there way I can catch the exception thrown by `THROW` statement in application level? I've read the `pyodbc` documentation and I can't see anything that might lead me to the solution.

Comment: have you tried using `nextset()` and *then* try to read? Or use `fetchall()`? In any case the problem is the stored procedure itself. You are just trying to find a work-around for the buggy `CATCH` statement. I suspect someone added the `SELECT` as a "debugging" statement or changed a `PRINT` to a `SELECT` to "print" a message in the results instead of properly handling the error

Comment: calling `nextset()`then `fetchone()` or  `fetchall()` does raise an exception from the `THROW` statement. I belive that is  an expected behavior knowing the following from ODBC docs
[processing results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-results/processing-results-odbc?view=sql-server-2017)

> Several other Transact-SQL statements return their data in messages rather than result sets.

Comment: Looks like this was an attempt to create "progress" notifications for a large job. `PRINT` messages don't appear in the results, one has to request them in a different way from the data library. The server doesn't send them immediatelly either, it can buffer them and only send them when there are enough of them.

Comment: A *better* approach is to create such a mechanism explicitly. Use logging tables and insert entries into them, including batch IDs, timings, parameters etc. That's how most ETL tools work.

Comment: This seems to be an open issue with pyodbc on Github atm: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/673